# How to add languages to pootle

Tags: pootle

Can someone tell me how to add languages in a new project in pootle?

I'm using pootle 2.7. I already added a new project but whenever I go projects//admin/languages/ , it gives a message "There are no templates for this project, so adding new languages from this screen is disabled."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to:

1. Have a *language* named `templates`, which includes the template files (*pot*) where the rest of languages will be initialized from. You can add these in the server's file system and import them via the [`update_stores` management command](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.7.0/server/commands.html#django-admin-update_stores). After that, the */projects/admin/languages/* screen will allow you to add new languages via the UI.
2. Have your languages directly imported via the command-line, also using the [`update_stores` management command](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/stable-2.7.0/server/commands.html#django-admin-update_stores)

Comment: Thanks!! I was actually putting the template file in the wrong folder. I should have put it inside the env/ . .. .